# Vue with Muuri - how to use?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm very new to Vue and my web dev skills are very limited, so sorry if this is a basic questions.

I just wanted to explore how I could create a draggable grid interface in the browser and found the Muuri package.

Now just following the example code in plain JavaScript/HTML the demo works as expected.

Now I try it with Vue, I get an error saying -
"TypeError: Cannot read property 'getRootNode' of null"

Here is my Vue component that should use Muuri.

```
<template>
  <div class="grid">

    <div class="item">
      <div class="item-content">
        <!-- Safe zone, enter your custom markup -->
        This can be anything.
        <!-- Safe zone ends -->
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="item">
      <div class="item-content">
        <!-- Safe zone, enter your custom markup -->
        <div class="my-custom-content">
          Yippee!
        </div>
        <!-- Safe zone ends -->
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</template>

<script>
  import 'web-animations-js';
  import Muuri from 'muuri';

  export default {
    name: 'Grid',
    created() {
      var grid = new Muuri('.grid', {dragEnabled:true});
      console.log(grid.toString());
    }
  }
</script>

<style scoped>
  .grid {
    position: relative;
  }
  .item {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    margin: 5px;
    z-index: 1;
    background: #000;
    color: #fff;
  }
  .item.muuri-item-dragging {
    z-index: 3;
  }
  .item.muuri-item-releasing {
    z-index: 2;
  }
  .item.muuri-item-hidden {
    z-index: 0;
  }
  .item-content {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
  }
</style>
```

Any help or advice much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is likely that the DOM hasn't loaded when the `created` event hook gets executed. You could try using `mounted` instead. I've included a snippet.

```js
new Vue({
    el: "#app",
    mounted() {
      var grid = new Muuri('.grid', {dragEnabled:true});
      alert(grid.toString());
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/web-animations-js@2.3.2/web-animations.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/muuri@0.8.0/dist/muuri.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app" class="grid">

    <div class="item">
      <div class="item-content">
        <!-- Safe zone, enter your custom markup -->
        This can be anything.
        <!-- Safe zone ends -->
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="item">
      <div class="item-content">
        <!-- Safe zone, enter your custom markup -->
        <div class="my-custom-content">
          Yippee!
        </div>
        <!-- Safe zone ends -->
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
```